# Setting up the page grid using push and pull

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap and I'm having issues setting up my grid. How do I use bootstrap's push/pull to setup my columns as below?

[image]

This is what I've got so far,

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3 col-md-3">A</div>
   <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-9 col-md-2 .col-md-push-7">B</div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 .col-md-pull-9">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you don't add a period (`.`) inside of the class attribute.
2. When using push/pull, you need to offset the columns from where they *would* normally go.  Moving them left or right won't change their underlying order in the document flow.

[image: Example]

So you can do it like this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5  col-sm-3  col-md-3"              >A</div>
  <div class="col-xs-7  col-sm-9  col-md-2 col-md-push-7">B</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-md-pull-2">C</div>
</div>
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets:

```css
.green  { background: #A3D7C3; }
.red    { background: #EF453A; }
.yellow { background: #FDBE2D; }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <h2> Normal </h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5  col-sm-3  col-md-3 green">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7  col-sm-9  col-md-2 red">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 yellow">C</div>
  </div>
  
  <h2> Push / Pull </h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5  col-sm-3  col-md-3               green">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-7  col-sm-9  col-md-2 col-md-push-7 red">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-md-pull-2 yellow">C</div>
  </div>

</div>
```